# STOMP and JSON

Tags: ajax, json, stomp

If I have a STOMP/JSON AJAX app, does that mean that JSON is functioning on top of STOMP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you mean [STOMP](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/stomp) (the protocol), not [STOMP](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/stomp/stomp.html) (the application), then JSON would be the data encoding method used over the STOMP messaging protocol.  You would be serializing your data as JSON, then packaging it inside a STOMP message to send to the other end point of the connection.